# nav menu is not working after implementing a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the tcycle slideshow, but after implementing my nav bar is under the picture, so most of the nav bar is not visible anymore.

Just have a look at the demo site: http://ibm.bplaced.com/notworking/

So what can I do to make the nav working again?

Thank you so much for your help! What about a cookie for every good answer? Isn't that a good idea? 0.0

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
nav ul li ul {
 z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do css:

`nav{position:relative; z-index:100}
.pagefull{position:relative; z-index:1}`

Comment: It still doesn't work :(